# CSS GRID position: relative

Tags: css, position, css-grid

I have been analyzing one of the "How to make blog website" tutorial. I have a question: why does it show all three columns when adding `position: relative` and without it, it only shows one column and one image?

```css
.post
{
    position:relative;  
}
.post .contentBx
{
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.post .contentBx .postColumn
{
    position: relative;

}
.post .contentBx .postColumn .postBox
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 20px;


}
```

```html
<!-- Latest posts  -->
    <section class="post" id="post">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>Latest Post</h2>
            <p>"Lorem</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contentBx">
            <div class="postColumn">
                <div class="postBox">
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <img src="images/post1.jpg" class="cover">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textBx">
                        <h3>Lorem

                        </h3>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="postBox">
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <img src="images/post2.jpg" class="cover">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textBx">
                        <h3>Lorem

                        </h3>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="postBox">
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <img src="images/post3.jpg" class="cover">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textBx">
                        <h3>Lorem

                        </h3>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="postColumn">
                <div class="postBox">
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <img src="images/post4.jpg" class="cover">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textBx">
                        <h3>Lorem

                        </h3>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="postBox">
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <img src="images/post5.jpg" class="cover">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textBx">
                        <h3>Lorem

                        </h3>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="postBox">
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <img src="images/post6.jpg" class="cover">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textBx">
                        <h3>Lorem

                        </h3>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="postColumn">
                <div class="postBox">
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <img src="images/post7.jpg" class="cover">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textBx">
                        <h3>Lorem

                        </h3>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="postBox">
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <img src="images/post8.jpg" class="cover">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textBx">
                        <h3>Lorem

                        </h3>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="postBox">
                    <div class="imgBx">
                        <img src="images/post9.jpg" class="cover">
                    </div>
                    <div class="textBx">
                        <h3>Lorem

                        </h3>
                        <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Why must `position` be set to `relative` for each class in CSS?

Comment: It's not necessary in normal layout so there must be something else going on. Can you provide a [mcve] with your CSS to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: You forgot to add the `.post` element which you've specified in every selector, so we can't (currently) reproduce your problem accurately. I realise it's likely just another `<div>` wrapping the `.postBox` elements, but unless you verify or show that it could be any number of ancestors away, or there could be multiple.

Comment: Also, your current CSS is set up so that `.postColumn` IS a column since it wraps all the child elements. It will not have 3 columns as `grid` is not inherited.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your input. 

I've added bigger piece of code above. I'm still wondering why the author of this code is adding position: relative in each section. Thanks

Comment: Having [removed all the `position: relative`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wytkp9a8/), I'm not seeing any obvious difference between that and your (current) [posted code](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wytkp9a8/2/). Are you seeing a difference, can you explain it to us?